# Editing already defined routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I'm working on a dynamic project which is adding or changing the route urls.
For example:
I want to add sub application route like AppName/{controller}/{action}/{id}
or maybe a language information like {controller}/{action}/{id}/{language}
in this scenario, I can't touch to other routes and I have to override them.

I tried to foreach RouteTable.Routes and there is no editable values for added routes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I cast the items in the RouteTable.Routes to Route object :)